# Extract the nth key in a python dictionary?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

Given a python dictionary and an integer `n`, I need to access the `n`th key. I need to do this repeatedly many times in my project.

I have written a function which does this:

```
def ix(self,dict,n):
    count=0
    for i in sorted(dict.keys()):
        if n==count:
            return i
        else:
            count+=1
```

But the problem is that if the dictionary is huge, the time complexity increases when used repeatedly.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Firstly remove `.keys()` for equivalent but faster code

Comment: there's nothing like "the nth element" in an unordered collection. you are phrasing the problem wrong I think.

Comment: @jamylak Ya, Thank you! I did't know that iteration can be done even without .keys(), and is there a solution for the main question?

Comment: @HemanthMalla what is your question?

Comment: What's the problem you actually want to solve? Conceptually, the "nth key of a dict" makes no sense, as a few other people have pointed out. You may be suffering from the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/201929).

Comment: I am implementing a btree using python dictionaries,so i sorted the keys, now i need to do few manipulations on the middle element and the  elements on the left and right of middle element, so i need to index through the keys..did i make my question clear? @Elazar, sorry for not being clear!

Comment: use [ordered dict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and the methods describe in the answers.

Comment: @Elazar: as of Python 3.6/3.7 you no longer need OrderedDict, dicts guarantee insertion order (and as a language feature in 3.7).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I guess you wanted to do something like this, but as dictionary don't have any order so the order of keys in `dict.keys` can be anything:

```
def ix(self, dct, n): #don't use dict as  a variable name
   try:
       return list(dct)[n] # or sorted(dct)[n] if you want the keys to be sorted
   except IndexError:
       print 'not enough keys'
```

Comment: Thank you @Ashwini , so internally python creates a list with all the keys in the dictionary rite?

Comment: @HemanthMalla No, python dicts are implemented as hash tables. http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#how-are-dictionaries-implemented

Comment: Do we really have to create an entire new list to access just one element?

Comment: Dictionaries /do/ have an order, since 3.6, and this is a language feature since 3.7.

Answer (score 15):

`dict.keys()` returns a list so, all you need to do is `dict.keys()[n]`

But, a dictionary is an unordered collection so nth element does not make any sense in this context.

> Note: Indexing `dict.keys()` is not supported in python3

Comment: it is an iterable in python3.

Comment: oops...I really need to upgrade this is my 2nd python3 correction for the day :)

Comment: dict.keys() is supported in python3, but dict.keys()[n] is not.

Answer (score 8):

For those that want to avoid the creation of a new temporary list just to access the nth element, I suggest to use an iterator.

```
from itertools import islice
def nth_key(dct, n):
    it = iter(dct)
    # Consume n elements.
    next(islice(it, n, n), None) 
    # Return the value at the current position.
    # This raises StopIteration if n is beyond the limits.
    # Use next(it, None) to suppress that exception.
    return next(it)
```

This can be notably faster for very large dictionaries compared to converting the keys into a temporary list first and then accessing its nth element.

Comment: you could do the same in one line by using `next(islice(it, n, n+1)) `

Comment: @raphael Sure, if writing things in one line is the goal, `next(islice(iter(dict), n, n+1))`.

Comment: Or making it more efficient... By the way, I don't know how it was back then, but now the answer is wrong. `islice(it, n, n)` gives stop iteration error for some reason. Also, if you want index `n`: `next(islice(d.keys(), n, None))`. If you want n'th key: `next(islice(d.keys(), n-1, None))`

Answer (score 2):

It is mentioned in multiple answers, that dictionaries were unordered. This is nonly true for python versions up to 3.6. From 3.7 ongoing, dictionaries are in fact ordered.