# How do I recall an item with an index from a tuple like {"A":1 , "B":2)

Tags: python-3.x, indexing, tuples, return

For the record, im a python noob
So dont expect to mutch of me.

Lets say i have a Tuple:,

```
Tuple = {1:'A',5:'B'}
```

how do I return the second item of this tuple?

I Tried googling it, but I couldnt find anything

I tried

```
Tuple = {1:'A',5:'B'}

return Tuple[1]
```

I wanted to return 5
But, It returned 'A'. I know why this is,
I just want to know how to return the 2nd item.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract the nth key in a python dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977385/extract-the-nth-key-in-a-python-dictionary)

Comment: `{1:'A',5:'B'}` is a dict, not a tuple. To get the nth key of a dict, do `list(d)[n]` (or in your example `list(Tuple)[1]` -> `5`).

Answer (score 0):

**Tuple = {1:'A',5:'B'}**
this is not a Tuple variable.
It is remaining a dictionary variable.

If You want To access this as a tuple, then you need to conver it into tuple .
For Example,

```
Tuple = tuple({1:'A',5:'B'})
return Tuple[1]
```

Now this will return 2nd element of Tuple.